# Searching for an alternative diode

Tags: diodes, datasheet

I'm looking for advice on finding an alternative diode for a negative feedback amplifier I'm repairing.

I hope there's a database I can search for specs and see some options.

M8513A-R Diodes Forward Reference Diode
If Max (A)
I(FSM) Max.(A) Pk.Fwd.Sur.Cur.
V(FM) Max.(V) Forward Voltage 620m
@I(FM) (A) (Test Condition) 3.0m
I(RM) Max.(A) Reverse Current 10u
@V(R) (V)(Test Condition) 5.0
Semiconductor Material Silicon
Package Style DO-35
Description: Junction Varistor for Temp/Bias Comp;Vf-2.1V/C

Comment: so, ok, you got the specs of the current diode down – but that doesn't tell us which of those are important to your application! so, you'll have to share the schematic that this device has, and what the diode does in particular.

Comment: (1) "*... an alterntative diode for a negative feedback amplifier ...*". What's wrong with the diode you've got? (2) Most of the online suppliers have parameterised component selection filters. (3) If you want someone to give you a part number then see [Don't ask](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Here's the schematic https://elektrotanya.com/toshiba_sc-335_stereo_amplifier_sch.pdf/download.html

Comment: The 3 original diodes on the right channel have failed.  The part appears to be discontinued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I hope there's a database I can search for specs and see some options.

You could use the parametric search of any major distributors. Among them I like [digikey's](https://www.digikey.com/) one.

Enter a keyword in the home page, select a category in the search result page and you'll enter the parametric search page. For example, searching for "diode" and then selecting "diodes - rectifiers - single" brings you [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/diodes-rectifiers-single/280?k=diode).

Have fun with that page!

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo, the digikey site is just what I had in mind.